# Image stretches horizontally

Tags: android, image, uiview

I am developing an app based on client-server application. I am using tablelayout, and in tablelayout am adding some textview, edit text and image( for click ). My screenshot is as follows: [image]

as you can see in my image add button blurs. It is just a 3kb file.

```
     final ImageView img_add_icon = new ImageView(MainScreen.this);
    img_add_icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_item_order);
```

and my xml file is:

```
     <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/add_to_order_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_margin="2dip"/>
```

What can I do to stop the blurring of this image?

Comment: use `setImageResource` instead of `setBackgroundResource`

Comment: post the whole layout. Ithink you are using some weight in layout or may be some other attribute which is making it like that. and chek the resulation of the image in drawable add_item_order

Comment: @SherifelKhatib. your are write it is just escape from mind..

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Use 

    setImageResource(resId)

    to Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView. 

    To Control how the image should be resized or moved to match the size of this ImageView
    use 

    setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType scaleType)


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29
  [2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29
```